# Requisição Ajax a uma API

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

Estou tentando fazer a requisição a uma API de terceiros através do seguinte código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function(){
      $.post({
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data:"1",
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic token'},
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
        }, error: function(err) {
          console.log('error')
        }
      });
    });

</script>
```

Porém estou tendo como retorno a seguinte mensagem.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'link-host' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'link-api'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Como resolver esse problema? Através do PHP eu consegui fazer a requisição.

Comment: Se sua página contém *SSL*, então o link da requisição deve haver *SSL* (*https*). No *PHP* isso é pode ser ignorado, por isso funciona. Há uma gambiarra que você pode fazer: Basta criar um arquivo `api.php` e utilizar o `cURL` para enviar os dados para API (de terceiros), receber o conteúdo, tratar e exibir para o usuário.

Comment: tenho que fazer apenas com JS =/

Answer (score 1):

Pedro, você consegue substituir o http da sua requisição JS por https?
Como o Ricardo disse, é necessário que sua requisição seja feita também em SSL, caso contrário o navegador fará o bloqueio do conteúdo misto (HTTP/HTTPS).

Quando você está realizando sua requisição por PHP seu arquivo certamente está operando sem SSL e por isso não há bloqueio, já que o conteúdo já foi retornado pela API.

Experimente realizar a solicitação com  `https://` na sua variável `url`.